# Wrong directory association in Cinnamon applets on Debian 8

Tags: debian, cinnamon, nemo

I'm on Debian 8 testing, installed Cinnamon together with the OS. It was working ~fine -some quirks here and there but nothing critical- until I compiled and installed [bomi](https://github.com/xylosper/bomi) (`make` + `make install`). Now the directories in Cinnamon applets (the `Rubbish Bin` applet, to name one installed by default) open with bomi.

Removing bomi from the PATH fixes the association back to Nemo. Needles to say, that's not the solution I'm looking for. Nemo opens fine if I chose it from the menu. Softlinked directories open with Nemo too. There's no "bomi" entry in `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`. So I guess that this is exclusively an error of how Cinnamon handles URIs.

Installing it the wrong way, with the deb package in the [developer's Ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/~darklin20/+archive/ubuntu/bomi/+packages) leads to the same result.

Could someone tell me where that config file is or, alternatively, how to continue troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ManIVIctorious said at GitHub](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/4769#issuecomment-152740493) that

> Could be linked to your personal mime app list. You could try to execute the following in a terminal:
>   `$ xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory`
>
> This should set nemo as default for opening directories.

which indeed solved the problem.